# User registration form validation in drupal 7

Tags: 7, users, forms

Drupal 7 comes with the built-in user registration form (user/register). I use this form for new users to register. Which is quite obvious. Now the problem is, and I find it hard to believe that it isn't there, I need some validating.

When a new user completes the form and hits submit, the account is being created. Good.

But: when a user completes the form and hits submit, but the email address or username is already in use, the pages just reloads and the user is not being created, which is good, but theres no warning on what he has to change in the form what so ever.

I find it strange that this is not standard.

Could anyone provide me some help? I really have no clue...

Comment: Check clear Drupal installation — it works and shows error messages via `drupal_set_message()`. So there are problems with your theme or contrib modules. You should provide more info about how did you modified you Drupal site.

Comment: there's something wrong with your theme or some custom modules you installed.

Comment: I use a self made theme. The register block is printed in a region on the page--webform.tpl.php. Is there an option to repair this?

Comment: Your theme should print `$messages`.  [Take a look](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob/30d1e719aa5e9a9ad66514078ca3b0975ddadc9c:/themes/bartik/templates/page.tpl.php#l161) at Bartik theme for example.